# paths for the package to ros envrionment variables, not found

Tags: ros, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, have a package with one cpp file, worked great. added another cpp file and built the workspace, now rosrun can't locate the package any more.
when creating the package I have implemented this command `echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc` , and have tried `rospack profile` which didn't list the path. why does this happen please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279580/paths-for-the-package-to-ros-envrionment-variables,-not-found/) by [finch1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33093/finch1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-01-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-01-11**:
Please edit your question to provide more information. There's not enough here to reproduce your problem. Please provide the full context of commands you're running with their outputs and any debugging commands you're trying as well.

**Comment by [finch1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33093/finch1/) on 2018-01-12**:
Hi tfoote,
There is not much I can add.

1. (terminal 1) catkin_make <- builds 100%
2. (terminal 2) roscore
3. (terminal 3) rosrun package_name <- double tab doesn't resolve path

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-12**:
Do you do a `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` after step 1? Your `.bashrc` is only evaluated when you open a new terminal, there is no magic there that makes `bash` update itself if/when you run `catkin_make`.

Without the `source` step, `rosrun` can't find your package.

**Comment by [finch1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33093/finch1/) on 2018-01-12**:
Hi gvdhoorn, so how come turtlesim works fine all the time? 
Isn't this the magic trick: `echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc` that makes `bash` update itself evertime `catkin` is run ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-12**:
No. Again: `.bashrc` is only evaluated (ie: read) when you start a new instance of `bash`. That is typically only when you start a new terminal.

See [What is the purpose of .bashrc and how does it work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143) for some more info on that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-12**:\

> how come turtlesim works fine all the time?

technical but: because the `turtlesim` packages were already present on the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` when you started your `bash` session.

Either in your `catkin_ws` or in `/opt/ros/$distro`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-12**:
And just to clarify: this is a "Linux thing", not something specific to ROS.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-12**:
If you can confirm that things work after you `source` the `setup.bash` after you built your workspace, I'll write an answer.

**Comment by [finch1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33093/finch1/) on 2018-01-12**:
Hi gvdhoorn, thanks for your patience and for explaining too. I read the link and makes better sense now. I tried again and for some reason its working ok now. I'm sure I'll encounter this prob again but I can better understand its fix now.

**Comment by [finch1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33093/finch1/) on 2018-01-12**:
Yes please, can write answer, was gonna ask for one actually, so I can tick. Yes, understood that this is a Linux thing, although wasn't sure who to ask.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-12**:
You would help yourself -- and us -- if you try to deduce why it now works. "for some reason" is not a very encouraging thing to say: it implies that you're not convinced that what posters here explained to you was the actual cause, and that you can't be bothered to find out what is/was.

**Comment by [finch1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33093/finch1/) on 2018-01-12**:
Hi gvdhoorn, no its not the case. I had my VM paused from yesterday, turned PC on, resumed VM, opened one terminal, typed roscore, opened another one, typed rosrun package_name, hit tab key twice and the exe appeared.

**Comment by [finch1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33093/finch1/) on 2018-01-12**:
I believe maybe the VM needs a "restart" to update. but honestly I haven't done any thing else. Otherwise of course I would have posted the fix.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-12**:\

> I believe maybe the VM needs a "restart" to update

no need. See my answer.

All of this is at the level of user programs, not OS or VM.

Read some of the related questions I included in my answer (especially the first one) to see *why* this is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I had my VM paused from yesterday, turned PC on, resumed VM, opened one terminal, typed roscore, opened another one, typed rosrun package_name, hit tab key twice and the exe appeared.

Every time you open a new terminal, a new `bash` session is started.

if you have your `.bashrc` setup to do `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` for you, then new terminals will cause your workspace to be `source`d.

If you add a package, build your workspace, then *don't* `source` it, the package will not be found.

If you now open a new terminal - as you say you did - *that terminal* will start a new `bash` session, causing your workspace to be `source`d. And as the new package has now been built, it will be added to the appropriate environment variables and can then be found - *in the new terminals* - by `rosrun` and `roslaunch`.

For already open terminals (really: `bash` sessions), just `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` yourself, and new packages should now be found.

---

Edit: some related questions:

- #q269784: *setup.bash every time?*
- #q229365: *Do I really need to $ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash ?*
- #q200174: *How to aviod running the command "source devel/setup.bash"*
- #q188309: *What does source command actually do?*

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [finch1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33093/finch1/) on 2018-01-12**:
Thanks gvdhoorn, in my .bashrc, at the very bottom, I can see the source link to the package, as you're describing. In case this happenes again, I'm more than happy to write how I fixed the issue. But from what I understood, as long as the .bashrc has the source link, there shouldn't be any issues.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-12**:\

> in my .bashrc [..] I can see the source link to the package

Just to be extra clear: the `source` line points to the [devel space](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces), not to any package.

It can't, because package directories do not contain the necessary files.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-12**:
Additionally: I only wrote about `bash`, but the same holds for other shells.

**Comment by [finch1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33093/finch1/) on 2018-01-12**:
Thanks for the helpful links. I asked the question as this happened to me already, so yeah, thanks for your detailed explenation. still getting my head around things.